# Alteryx to select top N records where N=a value on that group

Tags: partitioning, alteryx

I'm in a fix with Alteryx. I'm trying to select the top N rows where N=a cell value for that partition. The business question is:

> "We need to know, out of our orders (TicketIDs), those that have
>   least 1 combination of Type of discount item AND drink AND side."

The SQL query would join this table onto itself and partition to get the `TopNtoIncludeInItems` for that row, however, I just can't seem to find a way to do this in Alteryx. I've tried the community, but the question has gone ananswered.

In other words, select thusly:

```
<pseudocode>

for each (TicketID)
    for each(Type)
        select top(TopNtoIncludeInItems for this.TicketID) 
    next
next

</pseudocode>
```

or indeed select just the green records

[image: alteryx screenie]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

- MultiRow Formula: create new field `ComboCount` (or whatever) as Int32, 0 or empty for rows that don't exists, Group By TicketID and Type, with the Expression `[Row-1:ComboCount]+1` ... this counts up each group; we'll want the first *topN* of each group, ensuring the group actuall has that many, and not going beyond *TopN*.
- Filter on `[ComboCount] <= [TopN]` ... which excludes unnecessary rows beyond *TopN*
- Summarize: group by TicketID and Type, doing Max(ComboCount) ... if this value is less than *TopN* for any group, the group should be excluded:
- Join the summary back to the earlier pre-summary data on TicketID and Type
- Filter on `[Max_ComboCount] = [TopN]` ... this excludes the groups where any ItemType falls short of *TopN*

And that's it.  Pictorally, this is what my workflow looks like, along with data results based on data similar to that in your screenshot:
[image]

Comment: If you link to the question at the Alteryx Community, I can reply there also with a copy of the solution shown here.

Comment: Worked well. A great learning experience. I'm in your debt. I only had to do up to the second step to get the result I need. the requested linkhttps://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Designer-Discussions/Partitioning-by-Once-column-over-potential-multiple-row/m-p/197356#M50310